# Sending Automatic E-mails

Tags: .net, vb.net, email

I want to send an automatic E-mail based on the date. If the current date is greater than 5 days than the current date field in the table then i need to send an E-mail to the designated person. I am using VS.NET2003/VB.NET/ASP.NET/SQL Sever 2000. Can you guys help me how to get this done(if possible with Code?)
Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET-MVC?

Comment: Did you search Stack Overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+send+email

Comment: Were you looking for the rent-a-coder web site ?

Answer (score 1):

@vik18, I suggest that you give a look to [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).
Basically, you have to set it up at app start and set up a job that checks for some specific conditions every X time. If there are items, then you trigger some action like for example, sending an email.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

First you write some email code, as done here: http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/29.aspx

Then you connect to your table as seen here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28VS.71%29.aspx

Now you combine the two.  Loop through your data reader, check your date, and send email.  For bonus points filter your sql table for the date as seen here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173545%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Lastly, if you want to run as a service instead of a scheduled task: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/srinivaskotra/CreatingWindowservice10022009111806AM/CreatingWindowservice.aspx

I'd be more specific, but that's a pretty broad question with a lot of details.